# How do I make lilypond callable from pycharm virtualenv?

Tags: pycharm, lilypond

I'm trying to use abjad and lilypond in pycharm to generate music for a school project. However, after getting abjad and lilypond installed, I  can't seem to get abjad to work with lilypond.

I've tried following the instructions on the lilypond website. I read something about configuring my run configuration but can't seem to get it to work. I don't know how to add the path for the virtualenv in PyCharm.

I just get this in the run window "/bin/sh: lilypond: command not found" when I run some example code.

```
notes = [abjad.Note("ds'16"), abjad.Note("cs'16"), abjad.Note("e'16"), abjad.Note("c'16")]  
container = abjad.Container(notes)  
abjad.show(container)
```

EDIT 1: I tried adding /LilyPond.app/Contents/Resources/bin/lilypond to Interpreter paths in my Project Interpreter still with no success.

EDIT 2: That's what my interpreter paths look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec1E0.jpg

Comment: i believe you need to go to your pycharm settings/preferences and change your project interpreter to your virtualenv.

have you seen this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Comment: The project interpreter is already the virtualenv

Comment: hm we may be getting mixed up. the interpreter path is the location of the python executable, not the location of the lilypond executable. anyway that is probably not the issue if `abjad` is working.

check that the location of the lilypond executable is in your path. if not they try
`export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/LilyPond.app/Contents/Resources/bin/"`

Comment: tried that in the venv terminal in pycharm and in the os terminal since I'm not familiar with this I just tried both, still nothing

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you ran into is, out of the box, the MacOS Lilypond app does not expose its underlying command-line tool in a way that is easily accessible by other apps. The second part is that, even if you fix this problem, it's not super-obvious how to get the fix into PyCharm. Fortunately, both problems can be solved.

First, to explain the error. The error:

```
/bin/sh: lilypond: command not found
```

indicates that a shell script is trying to run `lilypond` without any particular location of the tool specified. MacOS will look at your `PATH` environment variable in that case to try to locate it.

Second, to correct a wrong path you were going down: do not use Interpreter Path for this. The only use of that is to tell PyCharm where the Python interpreter lives; you cannot use it to inform abjad where Lilypond lives. For that latter task, `PATH` is going to be your best bet.

There are a few ways to fix this, but the gist is: you need to update your `PATH` with some directory that contains the tool – but you also need to update it in a way where scripts launched by PyCharm pick up the updated `PATH`.

Generally, I do my `PATH` hacking in `~/.bash_profile`, since Bash is the default shell in MacOS, and this "script" gets loaded every time I start a Terminal (at least for recent versions of OS X/MacOS). To this script, add a line that looks something like this (making a backup of the script first!):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/LilyPond.app/Contents/Resources/bin/"
```

and save your change. Once you do this, if you launch a new Terminal window, you should be able to run `lilypond` and see Lilypond usage printed out.

Once you have that set up, I believe you merely need to quit and relaunch PyCharm, and it should pick up the new `PATH`. (Failing that, try logging out and in again.) In my version of PyCharm, I check that `PATH` is correct by going to the preferences, finding the settings "Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console", looking for a text field called "Environment Variables" (of which `PATH` is one), clicking on a "..." button just to the right of the text field to see details, making sure "Include parent environment variables" is checked, and then clicking on a "Show" link next to that checkbox to have PyCharm pop up a dialog with all of the environment variables it's passing along when it runs Python console operations. `PATH` should be listed there, and your Lilypond path should be included in its value.

---

I don't know about you, but I find it distasteful to have to put the guts of MacOS apps directly in my `PATH` like this, so there are a couple of other solutions I'll mention for completeness:

- Use symbolic links to make the tool appear in a directory that's already in your `PATH`. Using a Terminal, `cd` to the directory you want (I like `~/bin` for my personal tools, a directory which I created myself and added to my `PATH` a long time ao), and create a symbolic link to Lilypond thus: `ln -s /Applications/LilyPond.app/Contents/Resources/bin/lilypond .`.
- You can also install a pure command-line version of Lilypond into `/usr/local/bin` using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), a tool I find invaluable for wrangling Unix applications in MacOS. `/usr/local/bin`, so far as I know, should already be on your `PATH` (and if not, it's good to add it!). The problem with this approach – apart from multiple Lilypond installations running around on your machine, its version of Lilypond tends to lag a bit, which may cause problems with Abjad down the road. (It's currently on [2.18.2](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/lilypond), which is the latest stable version).